# If a cell in ColA contains a substring from a list in ColC, can that substring be returned in ColB?

Tags: string, excel, if-statement

I have a list of stems in ColC, and I want to search through ColA to see:

(1) Does the cell contain one of the substrings?
(2) Which substring does it contain?

I can do the first question in a variety of ways, including this:

```
=INDEX(C2:C25,MATCH(FALSE,ISERROR(FIND("*"&C2:C25&"*",A2)),0))
```

I just can't do the second, and return the value into ColB.

For example, A2 `abacavir` contains `vir` which is in the list (C25). I want B2 to say `vir`, rather than 'true' or '1'.

Also, is there any way that ColB could give multiple values if the cell in ColA contained more than one value from the list?

[image: sample of spreadsheet]

Answer (score 0):

VBA might be easiest here. Insert a module and paste the code below into it. Then make sure to select the sheet where your data is then run the macro titled "stem".

```
Sub stem()

Dim stem As String
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim f As Variant
Dim fRow As Long

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
i = 2

With ActiveSheet

    Do

        stem = .Cells(i, 3).Value

        With .Range("A1:A" & lastRow)

            Set f = .Find(stem, LookIn:=xlValues)

            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                fRow = f.Row
                ActiveSheet.Cells(fRow, 2).Value = stem
            End If

        End With

        i = i + 1

    Loop Until .Cells(i, 3) = ""

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @pnuts It's a stem so one possibility per row makes sense. Good point on first instance though.

Answer (score 0):

I agree VBA looks likely the most convenient overall, but certainly possible without. Delete C1 and copy C2:C25 into it with Paste Special..., Transpose. Populate C2 with:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&C$1&"*",$A2,0)),C$1,"")
```

copy across to Z2, then C2:Z2 down to suit. You should then have a matrix of what stem is found in which string.

To get the results in ColumnB use a long concatenation formula of the kind:

```
=TRIM(C2&" "&D2&" "&E2&" "&F2&" "&G2&" "& ... &Z2)
```

and copy down to suit.